# Why is an exception swallowed in an async action in a constructor?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, constructor, async-await, anonymous-function

I thought I was being clever in finding a way to call an aync method in a ctor:

```
public AppStateModel(IBranchClient branchClient)
{
    _branchClient = branchClient;
    var loadBranch = new Action(async () =>
    {
        DataProviderReadResult<BranchDetailViewModel> result = await _branchClient.ReadOneItemAsync(AppSettings.BranchId, _initCts.Token);
    });
    loadBranch();
}
```

But the body of the action throws an exception, which I log and re-throw with plain `throw;`, but this ctor executes fine and the rest of my code continues running as if nothing happens. Why is this?

Comment: Because it is `async`?  `loadBranch()` returns at the `await` if `_branchClient.ReadOnItemAsync()` has not yet completed. So the constructor returns successfully.

Comment: Why are you trying to call an async method in a constructor? Constructors shouldn't do any complex operations. Why not use a static method instead? That could then be a normal async method without any of this sillyness :)

Comment: @Luaan It's just a quick and dirty until I finish my current story, then I have another task on the board to do away with the silliness. I don't need to know how to make it work, because I would never do such a thing in the final code. I'm just asking because I'm curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the action is asynchronous. `loadBranch()` returns as soon as the first `await` is reached, and can't possibly throw the exception you're expecting - that's part of the information in the `Task` that you've ignored (by using `Action` instead of `Func<Task>`).

All in all, you've just written a more obfuscated version of this:

```
_branchClient.ReadOneItemAsync(AppSettings.BranchId, _initCts.Token);
```

.NET constructors are inherently synchronous. They shouldn't be doing anything where you'd benefit from using asynchronous code - and it's a good idea to do as little as possible in a constructor (or methods called by the constructor). If you need complex actions, asynchronous code, I/O, lots of CPU work... use a static method. And since you're running asynchronous code, make it return a `Task<AppStateModel>`, fitting properly in the whole asynchronous flow.

Also note that the exception will *not* be swallowed on older .NET runtimes. Assuming there's no synchronization context, the exception is still thrown on a background thread (where the continuation to the asynchronous operation is posted) - and the default for unhandled exceptions on thread-pool threads used to be "bring down the whole application". This would happen when the `Task` object was being finalized, so decoupled from all your program logic, pretty much random as far as you can tell. After all, what else can you do - there's no good place where the exception could be observed, and the only root there ever was basically said "I don't care about what happens with this task". But given how complicated it was to ensure that every single exception is properly observed and handled, the default was changed to "unobserved exceptions are ignored".

Comment: The exception won't ever be swallowed here. You're thinking of the unobserved task exception behavior, but this is `async void` (no `Task`). Based on the op's description, the exception just hasn't happened *yet* - it will show up if they let the whole app run.

Comment: Thanks, @Luaan. I was never planning to use this in 'real' code, it was more an experimental quick and dirty to get the branch loaded so I could concentrate on the story I was busy with that needed the branch. I just wanted an explanation of why what happened, and you gave a very good one.

Answer (score 2):

Let's deconstruct what happens here: You have an Action delegate that points to an anonymous `async void` method. What does `async void` mean? It means that the method actually returns a `Task` that encapsulates the async logic.

What it means is that when you call `loadBranch`, it executes an async method. When the async method hits the `await` call, it returns a `Task` object that allows you to wait on it, add a continuation, or whatever. But since you don't have an explicit Task variable to capture it, you just let your constructor go out of scope, without any code handling the continuation of the Task. This means that when the Task throws, the ctor has already exited.